# Generate id for files based on file content

Tags: c#, sql-server, file

I am using a upload mechanism for users to upload files and the user is suppose to receive 3 different file extracted from the uploaded one in an group which is identified by the uploaded file name.

I am trying to map the output files to it's parent file.
How can generate something unique that can be linked to the files so that they are easily associated to its group.

I am using C# and SQl Server Filestream to store the files in database.
The limitation that i am facing is that I cannot rename the file provided by user.
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: your formulation isn't exactly clear, but if you're just looking for a way to identify unique files, use a hash

Comment: using hash will collide if a user uploads same file more than one time in different folders.

Comment: as I said, your question is pretty hard to understand (example: what is a `parent file`)

Comment: I agree. afaik the database will always have a ```id``` property which is the primary key by default. Why not use those /w hash.

Comment: also if your main concern is that the hash may collide, maybe take the hash of the file's path appended to the content

Comment: I can't use the file path as the path is changed by moving the files from one volume to another.. 
As per your question parent file is the file that user uploads and using this file multiple output files are generated.

Comment: Take time of upload into the hash and you should be fine..

Comment: What if the user uploads a file that was previously uploaded with different name.